# How to format jQuery Mobile textboxes

Tags: textbox, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple jquery mobile page.  It has a header, a footer and the body has asks for login and password with textboxes, and then you can submit.

My problem is that jQuery Mobile makes the textboxes hold about 100 characters, making my entire display way too small.  Is there a way to force it to make the textboxes only hold about 12 characters and then make everything in the body larger?

Here is my code:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>heade</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="login.py" id="login_form" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="name" style="font-size: px; font-weight: bold;"> User Name: </label> 
            <input type="text" name="uname" minlength="3" />
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="password"> Password:&nbsp;&nbsp; </label> 
            <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>

                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the text-input elements to be only 12-characters *wide*, or to only be able to *hold* 12 characters, or both?

Comment: I mostly want it to be 12 wide and everything in content to be larger.

Answer (score 0):

I see this post is old, but maybe this will help someone...

Did you try adding something like this to your css?

```css
div input { width: 12px !important; }
```